# Making several rows in a column

Tags: tables

Hi guys I have this really weird table I made in word and want to make it in LaTeX since I am a noob in LaTeX I dont know how to split a column into several rows can some please tell me the coding how to do that I am attaching a picture of what I want 
[image]

I can make the first row but I down know how to split the second row into red green and blue rows

---

UPDATE

guys this is the code I am using

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ | 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{5cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} |} \hline
\bfseries{Oil Concentration} & \bfseries{Colour} & \bfseries{Oil} & \bfseries{Water} & \bfseries{Rock}\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{N-Decane + Oil Red O} & Red & 88 & 109 & 24 \\ \hline
& Green & 72 & 112 & 14 \\ \hline
& Blue & 58 & 105 & 13 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However now I have a new issue how do I remove the horizontal line in the first column between N-Decane + Oil Red O ???

[image]

Comment: a search for "multirow" mighthelp

Comment: @Bort there is no multirow here, just \cline{2-5}

Comment: @touhami okay fair point, but I think I would be better to use a multirow (or at least use the "green" line)

Comment: There might be \multirow s in the first column, if you want a smaller vertical spacing between the lines.

Comment: guys this is the code I am using its updated in the question above

Comment: see @touhami s comment replace \hline by \cline{2-5} (meaning a vertically centered line from column 2 to 5)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions, with vertical lines, and without, more ‘professional’ (requires the `booktabs` package). In both cases, I use the `makecell` package, that allows for a common formatting and line breaks is column and row heads, and `cellspace` for some vertical padding.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, makecell, cellspace} %
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
    \begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ |
      >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{5cm}
      | >{\centering\begin{eqminipage}[l]{COL}}p{2cm}<{\end{eqminipage}}
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}S{p{2cm}}
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} |} \hline
      \thead{Oil Concentration} & \thead{\makebox[0pt]{Colour}} & \thead{Oil} & \thead{Water} & \thead{Rock} \\
      \hline
      \multirowthead{3}[-1ex]{N-Decane + Oil Red O} & Red & 88 & 109 & 24 \\\cline{2-5}
                                                    & Green & 72 & 112 & 14 \\ \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Blue & 58 & 105 & 13 \\
      \hline
      \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Pentanoic Acid} & Red & 155 & 137 & 15 \\
      \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Green & 114 & 164 & 11 \\ \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Blue & 110 & 125 & 1 \\
      \hline
      \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Butyric Acid} & Red & 180 & 179 & 24 \\
      \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Green & 164 & 209 & 20 \\ \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Blue & 143 & 177 & 13 \\
      \hline
      \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Carboxylic Acid} & Red & 162 & 136 & 17 \\
      \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Green & 121 & 119 & 7 \\
      \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Blue & 95 & 107 & 0 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} %
        >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{5cm}
        >{\centering\begin{eqminipage}[l]{COL}}p{2cm}<{\end{eqminipage}}
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}S{p{2cm}}
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{Oil Concentration} & \thead{\makebox[0pt]{Colour}} & \thead{Oil} & \thead{Water} & \thead{Rock} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-5}
        \multirowthead{3}[-1ex]{N-Decane + Oil Red O} & Red & 88 & 109 & 24 \\
                                                      & Green & 72 & 112 & 14 \\
                                                      & Blue & 58 & 105 & 13 \\
        \addlinespace
        \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Pentanoic Acid} & Red & 155 & 137 & 15 \\
                                                      & Green & 114 & 164 & 11 \\
                                                      & Blue & 110 & 125 & 1 \\
        \addlinespace
        \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Butyric Acid} & Red & 180 & 179 & 24 \\
                                                      & Green & 164 & 209 & 20 \\
                                                      & Blue & 143 & 177 & 13 \\
        \addlinespace
        \multirowthead{3}{N-Decane + Oil Red O & & & & \\ $ + {}$ Cyclo Hexane\\ Carboxylic Acid} & Red & 162 & 136 & 17 \\
                                                      & Green & 121 & 119 & 7 \\
                                                      & Blue & 95 & 107 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presented here is one possible way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Oil Concentration & Colour & Oil & Water & Rock \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{N-Decane + Oil Red O} & Red & 88 & 109 & 24 \\ \cline{2-5}
& Green & 72 & 112 & 14 \\ \cline{2-5}
& Blue & 58 & 105 & 13 \\ \cline{2-5}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{4cm}{N-Decane + Oil Red O  + Cyclo Hexane  Pentanoic Acid}} & Red & 153 & 137 & 15 \\
\cline{2-5}
& Green & 114 & 164 & 11 \\ \cline{2-5}
& Blue & 110 & 125 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{4cm}{N-Decane + Oil Red O + Cyclo Hexane  Pentanoic Acid}} & Red & 153 & 137 & 15 \\
\cline{2-5}
& Green & 114 & 164 & 11 \\ \cline{2-5}
& Blue & 110 & 125 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{4cm}{N-Decane + Oil Red O + Cyclo Hexane Pentanoic Acid}} & Red & 153 & 137 & 15 \\
\cline{2-5}
& Green & 114 & 164 & 11 \\ \cline{2-5}
& Blue & 110 & 125 & 1 \\ \cline{2-5}
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]