# how to make the below table

Tags: tables

I am new with latex. I know how to make the table but do not know how to combine two rows or columns.

[image]

Comment: This is a do-it-for-me question. Please show what you've got so far.

Comment: To combine columns use `\multicolumn`. The command is described in almost every LaTeX introduction like [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/). For rows there are already questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256874/making-several-rows-in-a-column

Comment: your table have more issues: (i) table design is not consistent, (ii) writing of numbers is not consistent (wrong), you can not expect that some one here will retype your table. You should provide what you try so far and show where you stuck.

Comment: not getting how to merge the cells which contains 14,23,200.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e - How, please, should one interpret "numbers" that contain commas separated by only two (rather than three) digits?

Comment: Load the `multirow` package and code `\multirow{4}{*}{14, 23,200}`.

Comment: Is there any guiding principle to explain why some number triples are centered even though most others are right-aligned?

Comment: @Mico. The table that is shown is definitely badly designed and rather ugly, imho. Look for instance the first empty line under the heading, the changes between dots and commas on line `3`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problematic part, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|*7{r|}}
    \hline
    1 & Equipment  & 3,48,200 & 3,48,200      &    & 3,36,578 &  & 3,36,578 & 11,622 \\    \hline
    2 & Consumable & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{14,23,200} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{3,91,800} & & 8,445 & & 8,445 & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{19,946} \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{5-8} 3  & Travels       &    &    &        & 14,377   &    & 8,445    &  \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{5-8} 4  & Contingencies &    &    &        &          &    &          &  \\
    \cline{1-2}\cline{5-8} 5  & Manpower      &    &    & 94,032 & 2,55,000 &    & 3,49,032 &  \\  \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]